# Editing .java files in VSCODE causes error on Tomcat in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, visual-studio-code

I'm working on some legacy code in JAVA.
It's like "pure java" with JSP and servlets, no maven and no spring boot.
I usually use VSCODE but the "way it's always been done" is with ECLIPSE and TOMCAT with some special configurations and a keystore.

My problem is: after I modify a .java file on VSCODE the TOMCAT starts giving up the errors:

```
ago 28, 2020 11:42:13 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
ADVERTÊNCIA: The web application [header] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connecti
on cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
 com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:40)
ago 28, 2020 11:42:13 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
```

And I have no idea why or how to fix. I end up having to revert the changes, copy and paste the changes inside Eclipse. And then it works, even GIT says there's no changes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea why, but excluding and then reading any file from buildpath seems to be the trick.

Maybe just touching the ".classpath" file should be enough.

That file doesn't appear in Eclipse by default, but does in VSCODE. Its located in the root folder of the project.

It appears you don't need to keep doing this every time.
I'm using git flow and only as I've changed to a new feature branch I had to do this again.

Comment: The Package Explorer and Project Explorer Views have a filter for .* named files on by default. It's always there, just hidden.